# Unity AR How can i trigger a button in the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have this little AR-Unityapp for Android and i try to play a video with a button. But the button should not be on the screen ( canvas ) it should be in the scene ( understandable? ). So i made a 3d plane which simply starts the video with a pointer down event but it won´t work. I know that its possible to make this but i have no idea how some help would be helpful ( xP ).

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use [virtual buttons](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Implement-Virtual-Buttons)

Comment: i already have some virtual buttons for some other stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a world canvas:

Create a canvas and set its "render mode" to "world".
In that canvas you can put your button, give it a 3D location as you would with your plane, but you can use normal UI functionalities, such as buttons, instead of implementing click detections your self.

Comment: Or make an IPointerClickHandler behaviour and add a physics raycaster in.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger a Pointer Down event just follow the steps below

### **STEPS**

1. Add Physics Raycaster to your Camera as shown below
   [image: Physics Raycaster]
2. Add EventSystem object in your scene 
   Right click in Hirarchy Window -> UI -> Event System
3. Attack Event Trigger component to the required plane
   Select Plane -> Add Component -> Event Trigger -> Add Event of Pointer Down[image]
4. Now Call the Required method via PointerDown Event (In My case Plane.OnSelected())

### **ALTERNATIVE OF EVENT TRIGGER**

1. Steps 1 to 2 as above
2. Attach the below Script to that Plane as below

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

   public class Plane : MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler {
       public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
       {
           Debug.Log("CALLED");
       }
   }
   ```

   This Method will be called on Pointer Down on the required plane. 
   As Seen in the above code we are using `IPointerDownHandler` interface of `UnityEngine.EventSystems`

I am sure this will clear your problem.

Comment: thx for the answer very useful if i dont want to use the canvas method :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. :)